# Oracle Application Server 10g Portal

Tags: oracle

Всем привет.

Есть веб портал, который находится на платформе Oracle Application Server 10g Portal. 
Прошу немного помочь с консультацией.
Какой язык программирования используется на данной платформе? PHP, Java, C# или какой то другой?
Какие особенности данной платформы?
И ссылки на примеры разработок порталов на этой платформе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ЕМНИП java